# Resolving hosts in the same VPC using AWS Fargate

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I have a VPC with N instances. The VPC has a hosted zone in Route53, and every instance has a record on it, so that they can communicate with each other using the name. For example:

```
$ nslookup etcd
Server:     127.0.0.53
Address:    127.0.0.53#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   my.hosted.zone
Address: 10.0.0.16
```

Some of these instances are for Docker containers and I want to get rid of them and run these containers on ECS+Fargate.

The problem I'm facing is that, when running the containers on Fargate (using same VPC), they can't resolve the name. However, if instead of the name, I use the IP, everything works, so it's not a problem of security groups but of DNS. Name resolution works without Fargate, so it's not a problem of misconfiguration in the VPC either (anyway, both DNS hostnames and resolution are enabled).

What might be issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I found the answer.

Indeed, there is name resolution if using the same VPC. My problem was that I was used to reference the host by its hostname, for example `etcd`, but the actual record is `etcd.my.hosted.zone`.

Using instances, resolution worked only with hostname because the `/etc/resolv.conf` has `search my.hosted.zone`